# Timezones in Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, timezone

I have an application that stores its timestamps in Oracle using UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). Another application reads these timestamps from the database, but there is no convenient way to convert the timestamps to another timezone automatically (from within that application). Is it possible to adjust session settings in Oracle to return timezone adjusted timestamps for SELECT queries?

Comment: What data type are you using to store the data?  `TIMESTAMP`?  `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?  Or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`?

Comment: A regular TIMESTAMP.

Comment: You can use `FROM_TZ` to convert a timestamp to a timestamp in a different timezone: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions068.htm#i999803

Comment: Is there a way to do this implicitly with every `SELECT` and `UPDATE`? So for example, the database's timezone is set to UTC but the session timezone is set to EST. So any `SELECT` that happens would automatically return time in EST...

Comment: @DylanKlomparens - The automatic conversion of time zones is something that the `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type does.  You're not even storing a time zone with your data so Oracle has no idea that it should assume that they are UTC.

Comment: @JustinCave - The database itself has a timezone setting. `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;` reveals this. So I suppose the database should assume all `TIMESTAMPS` use that timezone. Session timezone is revealed through `SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @DylanKlomparens - I guess the database could assume that any `TIMESTAMP` is in the database time zone.  But it doesn't.  If you specify `TIMESTAMP` rather than `TIMESTAMP WITH [LOCAL] TIME ZONE`, you specify that you don't care about the time zone.  How much of this is dictated by the SQL 99 standard for those data types and how much is an Oracle implementation detail is not something that I know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the data is stored in a `TIMESTAMP` column, you cannot automatically convert it.  You'll have to write some code that tells Oracle what time zone to treat the data as being stored in the `GMT` time zone and tell it that you want it converted to the session's time zone.  You would get the automatic behavior you are looking for if you used the `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data type instead.  If you used the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type, you would avoid having to tell the database what time zone the timestamp comes from when you write the conversion.

Assuming that your session sets its time zone properly

```
ALTER SESSION SET time_zone = '-8:00'
```

for example, would tell Oracle that the current session is 8 hours before GMT (currently the Pacific time zone), if the data is stored in a `TIMESTAMP` column, you'd need something like

```
FROM_TZ( ts, 'GMT' ) AT TIME ZONE sessiontimezone
```

If the data is stored in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, you'd just need

```
ts_tz AT TIME ZONE sessiontimezone
```

If the data is stored in a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column, you would just select that column.

An example

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table foo(
  2    ts timestamp,
  3    ts_tz timestamp with time zone,
  4*   ts_local_tz timestamp with local time zone )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into foo
  2    values( sys_extract_utc( systimestamp ),
  3            systimestamp,
  4*           systimestamp )
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> select from_tz( ts, 'GMT' ) at time zone sessiontimezone ,
  2         ts_tz at time zone sessiontimezone,
  3         ts_local_tz
  4    from foo;

FROM_TZ(TS,'GMT')ATTIMEZONESESSIONTIMEZONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TS_TZATTIMEZONESESSIONTIMEZONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TS_LOCAL_TZ
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 01.59.03.171000 PM -08:00
02-MAY-13 01.59.03.171000 PM -08:00
02-MAY-13 01.59.03.171000 PM
```

In response to the comment below from DylanKlomparens -- you cannot just apply the `AT TIME ZONE` to a `TIMESTAMP` and expect to get the proper result so I'm not sure that I understand what you are seeing.  If you just to an `AT TIME ZONE` on a plain `TIMESTAMP`, the timestamp is simply treated as having the time zone that you specified.  It doesn't change the time.  It also doesn't depend on the session time zone.  In all these cases, if `ts` represents a `UTC` time, the `PST` version represents the wrong time-- there should be an 8 hour difference between the starting and ending values.

```
SQL> select ts from foo;

TS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 09.59.03.171000 PM

SQL> select ts at time zone 'PST' from foo;

TSATTIMEZONE'PST'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 09.59.03.171000 PM PST

SQL> alter session set time_zone = '-0:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select ts at time zone 'PST' from foo;

TSATTIMEZONE'PST'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 09.59.03.171000 PM PST

SQL> alter session set time_zone = '-4:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select ts at time zone 'PST' from foo;

TSATTIMEZONE'PST'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 09.59.03.171000 PM PST
```

In response to Vincent's comment-- A `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` does adjust automatically to the session's time zone regardless of the server's time zone.  As I adjust my session's time zone, the results change as well.

```
SQL> select ts_local_tz from foo;

TS_LOCAL_TZ
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 05.59.03.171000 PM

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> alter session set time_zone = '-0:00';

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> select ts_local_tz from foo;

TS_LOCAL_TZ
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-MAY-13 09.59.03.171000 PM

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> alter session set time_zone = '+4:00';

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> select ts_local_tz from foo;

TS_LOCAL_TZ
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-MAY-13 01.59.03.171000 AM

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, Justin! I tried this out in a test database and found that I can `SELECT my_time_column AT TIME ZONE 'PST' FROM test_table;`, where `my_time_column` is a `TIMESTAMP`. It appears that setting the session timezone globally influences the TIMEZONE type.

Comment: @DylanKlomparens - I updated my answer.  You can't just do an `AT TIME ZONE` on a plain `TIMESTAMP` assuming you want the time component to change.  Either you actually have a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or something else is going on.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE` are set at the **server** time zone, not the client time zone. Changing **session** time zone won't change the output of a query.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - I updated my answer to show that the results are returned based on the session's time zone.

Comment: Oops you're right, I messed up my test case !